# Unable to Copy & Paste to asp Text Box asp.net C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a mobile No in my system and I have a asp textbox the issue in here is unable to copy & paste the mobile no to this asp textbox. I have a Onkeydown function for only accept the numbers.

> > I need to Copy & Paste the No to this textbox.

### Code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMobileNo" runat="server" autocomplete="off" 
    AutoCompleteType="Disabled" MaxLength="10" 
    onkeydown="return (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || 
        (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) || event.which == 8 || 
        event.which == 46;"
    Style="height: 25px;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the JS simply returns true or false. I just tried to paste using `Ctrl+V` and nothing happens, presumably because the JS is reading my keystrokes for pasting, and they are not numbers.

But if I right-click the mouse and select paste, it works.

You might have to get rid of the JS, or add more keyCodes to accept `Ctrl+V`.

Answer (score 0):

To allow users pasting with Ctrl+V or Cmd+V check for those `keyCode` in your `onkeydown` event, then check if the pasted text is a number in the `onpaste` event, here's a complete example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMobileNo" runat="server" 
autocomplete="off" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" MaxLength="10"
onkeydown="return validateInput(event);"
onpaste="validateClipboard(event)"
Style="height: 25px;" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    function validateInput(event) {

        // Check if Ctrl+V or Cmd+V was pressed
        if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && event.keyCode == 86) {
            return true;
        // Check if numbers input
        } else if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) ||
            (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) ||
            event.which == 8 || event.which == 46) {
            return true;
        }
        // All checks failed
        return false;
    }

    function validateClipboard(event) {

        // Prevent clipboard data pasting
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        // Get clipboard text data
        var clipboardData = event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
        var pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');

        // Check if pasted data is a number, if true paste to text box
        if (isNaN(pastedData) === false) {
            var txtBox = document.getElementById('MainContent_txtMobileNo');
            txtBox.value += pastedData;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what sort of number format you are going to match, I will assume you have a number in this format `9999999999` (a ten digits number).

Here is the best solution that I can think of:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMobileNo" runat="server" autocomplete="off"
        AutoCompleteType="Disabled" MaxLength="10"
        onblur="return validateNumber(this)"
        Style="height: 25px;" />
```

Notice, instead of `keydown` event, I have used `onblur` event, that is because, it is a good practice to check the number after they have completed typing in the text box and when they leave the textbox.

```
<script>
    function validateNumber(evt) { // this will get executed when user has stopped typing or pasting the value. 
        var isValid = isValidMobileNumber(evt.value);
        if (!isValid)
        {
            evt.value = ''; // Clear if the number is not valid.
        }

        return isValid;
    }
    function isValidMobileNumber(number) {
        var phoneRegex = /^\d{10}$/; /* to verify 10 digits in number */
        /* var phoneRegex = /^[2-9]\d{2}[2-9]\d{2}\d{4}$/; // to verify 10 digits number with (-) in it. 999-999-9999 */
        var digits = number.replace(/\D/g, "");
        return phoneRegex.test(digits);
    }
    // The code below can be removed, read the explanation below the code.
    document.getElementById('<%= txtMobileNo.ClientID %>').addEventListener('paste', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        if (isValidMobileNumber(text))
            window.document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
    });

</script>
```

Notice, I have bound a `paste` event with your textbox, which will be triggered every time immediately after someone pastes something in the textbox. But, technically, you can remove this event from here and the program will work fine that is because the `onblur` event will be triggered anyway after you have pasted the data which will eventually validate the pasted data. So, it is upto you, either you want to immediately validate the data when pasted or you want it to be validated when the user leaves the control (After pasting or typing whatever).